# Substituting canola oil in salad

Tags: substitutions, oil

I have a recipe for Asian salad using canola oil and rice vinegar.  Is there a substitution for canola oil that will not be changing the flavor? I would prefer to not use vegetable oil.

Comment: What do you mean by "not vegetable oil"? — Canola, corn, safflower, peanut, coconut, soy, etc., etc., are all vegetable oils. Non-vegetable oils would be either animal or mineral. Some types of fish oil are purportedly quite healthy, but I imagine they would impart a strong flavor. I also don't think you'd want to dress a salad with mineral oil.

Comment: We don't discuss health topics here. We can recommend oils but not make any claims about health.

Comment: @ElmerCat I'm guessing the op means the product sold in the US as "vegetable oil". Depending on brand it can be a wide variety of bases.

Comment: usually virgin olive oil works perfectly with salads, and it is very healty. can u specify at least what ur salad contains to help u find some oil that goes with it?

Comment: @Zeina olive oil is not flavorless. It is very flavorful.

Comment: @Catija yes sorry ddnt pay attention for this part in the question...

Answer (score 1):

Canola oil is a neutral oil (meaning it has little/no flavor of itself) so you need another neutral oil to work. If you want to avoid vegetable oil (which in USA usually means soybean oil), you can try peanut oil, sunflower oil, or safflower oil. These are all neutral oils and should not change the flavor of the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've found to an oil that imparts no taste to foods is grapeseed oil. It's my go-to even for making fries.